# What happens in Inno Setup uninstaller to Registry keys without flags?

Tags: inno-setup

If I have following line in my `[Registry]` section of my Inno Setup script

```
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\MySoftware"; ValueType: string; \
    ValueName: "ApplicationDescription"; ValueData: "My cool software";
```

what will happen when uninstalling? Do I need to add `flags: uninsdeletevalue;` if it should be removed on uninstall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explicitly written in [`[Registry]` section documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection):

> By default, registry keys and values created by Setup are not deleted at uninstall time. If you want the uninstaller to delete keys or values, you must include one of the `uninsdelete*` flags described below.

Comment: I really don't understand why it does not delete keys by default. Oh well!

Comment: I had searched for such a statement, but in the flags section...

Comment: The likely reason that IS does not delete registry entries by default is that the setup author may use them to store configuration data for the application, and it doesn't know what should be removed vs. what shouldn't be, so the impetus is on the setup script author to specify _precisely_ what should be removed.